# upload multiple images in magento admin module

Tags: image, magento, upload, module

i am new to magento extension development. i am trying to learn the basics of magento extension development, for this i have start to create new module . in this

> **i want to display multiple images in the admin backend.**

I have the following code in my system.xml

```
<logo translate="label comment">
<label>Logo</label>
<comment>Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.</comment>
<frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
<base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</logo>
```

> With this only one image is showing in the admin,

which is latest uploaded.

> **i want to display all the images , which are saved in the above media directory**

Suggest me how can i do it.

Thanks